# Why or how do .bashrc/.bash_profile files work for Windows

Tags: windows, bash

I learned about using .bashrc and .bash_profile files using MacOS but it appears I can create command line aliases using .bashrc files in Windows, where said file is placed in my user directory. Since when was this possible? The Windows command line is not Bash, after all, so what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, you need a Bash console of some sort before you can make use of `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile` scripts as you're used to on MacOS.

Most people use the `Git Bash` console that comes out of the box when installing `Git` for Windows. Of course you'll be able to use the `.bash_profile` script from `Git Bash`, not from `Command Prompt` directly.

Here's a nice blog post about setting up Linux-style development environment on Windows: https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-a-functional-and-sleek-console-in-windows